# Finding the creation date of the guild in the correct format, using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `serverinfo` command, and I wanted to add `Server CreationDate`.

This should give the `Date`, `Time` and `How long ago`.

But the issue is when I use `message.guild.createdAt` the output looks like this:

```
Sat Sep 04 2021 09:44:44 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

It's too long AND it looks bad, I'm wondering if I can have the output look something like this?

```
09/04/2021 11:44 (3 months and 10 days ago)
```

Here is my code:

````js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'serverinfo',
    category: 'Info',
    description: 'Shows info about the server.',
    aliases: [],
    usage: 'Serverinfo',
    userperms: [],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;

  let staffcount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.ROLE_STAFF).members.size;
  let botcount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.ROLE_BOT).members.size;
  let membercount = message.guild.memberCount - botcount
  let verifiedcount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.ROLE_MEMBER).members.size - staffcount

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }))
      .setColor("BLUE")
      .setTitle(':desktop: SERVER INFORMATION :desktop:')
      .addField('Server Name', '```' + message.guild.name + '```',true)
      .addField('Server Owner', '```SirDevinci#1998```',true)
      .addField('Server Members ['+ membercount +']', '```' + verifiedcount + ' Verified Members | ' + staffcount + ' Staff Members```',false)
      .addField('Server Tier','```' + message.guild.premiumTier + '```',true)
      .addField('Server Boosts','```' + message.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount + '```',true)
      .addField('Server CreationDate','```' + message.guild.createdAt + '```',false)
      message.channel.send(embed);
  }
}
````

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format your datetime:

````js
const moment = require('moment');

// and then use this to format time
let createdAt = moment(message.guild.createdAt);
let dateFormated = createdAt.format('DD/MM/YYYY')+'( '+ createdAt.fromNow() +' )';

// then use it on your output: 
 .addField('Server CreationDate','```' + dateFormated + '```',false)
````